# Automatic printing based on URL

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

FYI not looking for code, just pointers in the right direction ;)

Our ticketing system allows us to print off labels that we stick onto customers stuff and prints off our terms of trade for the customer to sign. The terms of trade I have managed to get to print automatically by opening with an external PDF viewer (it does leave a blank tab open after download but meh.) however the labels are still a bit of a pain to print as Chrome takes it's time generating previews and checking if printers are online & able to print.

I'm looking for something that will print to the default printer (closing the tab afterwards would be cool too!) based on URL (i.e if it contains labels.php?id=*&a=print&notes=1).

Currently using Chrome but open to switch to whatever will work, the PC used is dedicated to only entering new tickets.

Have looked into AutoHotKey (no longer supports URL grabbing in Chrome) SeamlessPrint (requires a request for something to be printed) Automatic Print (just didn't work!) and iMacros (has no printing support and isn't activated based on Macro)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered generating the labels within a pdf file also?

Comment: Certainly had! this would be the best way to go although the problem being that labels and terms of service are different printers, a4 and address label sized labels. Yet to find any software that will watch folders and print to different printers, any suggestions here are welcome also!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nic! I will let you know how it goes